# Is there any way to know how many users currently using ColdFusion application server

Tags: coldfusion, application-server

Is there any way to know how many users are currently using ColdFusion application server?

I need to restart the ColdFusion server and would like to choose a time when least number of users are currently active. Can I get this kind of info via ColdFusion Administrator or do I just have to guess the best time of day?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could just look at your webserver logs to get an idea of the time which typically has the least amount of traffic.

Comment: If uptime is important, cluster two servers so when one goes down the other can take over.

Answer (score 1):

we may not accurately count that, but I have had success in getting the count based on sessions.

For every user you have on the website, ColdFusion creates a session for them. so count your sessions and you know how many users are there on the website right now.

```
<cfscript>
    /* the sessions object */
    sessions = createObject("java","coldfusion.runtime.SessionTracker");

    /* get the whole session count on the server right now */
    writeoutput(sessions.getSessionCount());

    /* get the whole session count on the server right now for a specific application */
    writeoutput(structCount(sessions.getSessionCollection('A SPECIFIC APPLICATION NAME IF YOU WANT')));
</cfscript>
```

**Note**: this may not be proper when your session never expires for a specific application. but, nevertheless an option to explore.

you can have a scheduler that runs this code every hour and keeps a log of that. you will have your day statistics to get the best time to do a app server restart.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of the web server logs, FusionReactor information, and the CF Server Monitor to get an idea of the usage patterns for the site. You can see the usage patterns fairly easily this way.